# Rails-devise: Generating encrypted_password values (for test users)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, blowfish, bcrypt

To test my Rails/Devise application, I want to create 100 users and log in as them.

I tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO users (id,email,encrypted_password)
  VALUES (11,"test1@example.com",
    "$2a$10$VQJ9lT78.e1dtyAnkng1/ey9euL6hK/kUNQMDv8VJMAovXpuVNDZG");
```

For the `encrypted_password`, I just copied the value from another user whose password is `testtest`

PROBLEM: I can't log as `test1@example.com` with password `testtest`

I suspect `encrypted_password` has salt and I need a tool to generate it. `config.encryptor` is `bcrypt`. I installed bcrypt (Linux) but the man page is very short and only explains how to encrypt files, so I guess it is not the most convenient tool to salt passwords.

How to quickly create the 100 salted passwords?
Something faster than signing up 100 times.

Comment: In Devise's source code, the hash seems to be create by this line: `::Digest::SHA512.hexdigest('--' << tokens.flatten.join('--') << '--')` Now I have to find what are the tokens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making `u = User.create(:email => 'youruser@mail.com', :password => 'testtest', :password_confirmation => 'testtest')` and then `u.confirm!` (if you are using the confirmable module) from your tests should generate the encrypted_password for the user correctly.

Anyway you should considerate using fixtures or blueprints for your tests.

Comment: It is failing in `devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb` saying `Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]`... That's why I was trying to avoid business logic code. I will try to disable email confirmation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about fixtures and blueprints! Please note that it is a full-scale test with 100 real people.

Comment: Add 'config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }' in your "config/environments/test.rb" and it should work.